# Creating a basic music sequencer with Minim library in Processing - trouble with looping

Tags: processing, minim

I've started on a project to create a music sequencer with minim using instrument classes and playNote functions etc. I've got a sequence of notes working ok, but I have no way of looping them. Here's the main code:

```java
import ddf.minim.*;
import ddf.minim.ugens.*;

Minim       minim;
AudioOutput out;
Delay myDelay;
int i;
int endSeq;

public void settings() {
  size(800, 300, P2D);
}

void setup() {

  minim = new Minim(this);
  out = minim.getLineOut();
  myDelay = new Delay(1.5,0.5, false,false);
  bassSeq(); // starts bass sequence function
  chordSeq(); // starts chord sequence function
}

void draw() {
}
```

And here's the bassSeq function which describes the whole bass sequence:

```java
void bassSeq(){
float[] stepArray = {0.00, 0.75, 2.00, 2.5, 2.75, 3.5, 4, 4.5};
float[] decayArray = {1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0};
float[] noteArray = {C2, F2, E2, G2, B2, C2, C2, B2};

for (i = 0; i <= 7; i++){

  out.pauseNotes();
  out.setTempo(125);
  out.playNote(stepArray[i], decayArray[i], new BassInstr(noteArray[i], 0.5, out ) );
  out.resumeNotes();

}
}
```

The problem is, if I put these functions in setup, they only play once. What ideally I'd want to do is iterate back to the start of i=0 so it gives the instruments the sequence from the start of the array after it is finished one loop. If I put the sequence functions in the draw loop, it sends the instrument notes incredibly fast (prob around 60fps if that's the default for draw). I've put a delay() function in the draw loop which does actually loop the music after the time but there's no way of giving delay a number that is totally accurate so it loops accurately.

Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please link between crossposts: https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/19217/making-a-basic-music-sequencer-with-minim

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `frameCount` variable and the modulo `%` operator to take an action every X frames. More info on both can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/).

Here's a little example that draws a random circle every 60 frames:

```java
void draw(){
  if(frameCount % 60 == 0){
   ellipse(random(width), random(height), 15, 15);   
  }
}
```

You could do something similar, only instead of drawing circles, you'd be playing notes.